# Find all cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Find all cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$.

I know the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ to be $\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 2\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 3\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 4\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 6\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 8\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 12\mathbb{Z}_{24}, 24\mathbb{Z}_{24}=\langle0\rangle$.

Which of these are cyclic and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is cyclic (it is generated by the element $1$), and [a subgroup of a cyclic subgroup is cyclic](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic), all the subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ cyclic?

Comment: Well $\mathbb Z_{24}$ is assumed to be $\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z$. Do you mean it not to be?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{24} = \langle 1\rangle$.

Comment: @IanColey No, just wondered. Its cyclic groups that I'm having troubles with.